# importing AND exporting form fields

Tags: vba, import, ms-word, export

I have a Word form with macros in it. And I'd like to import and export those form fields into another application such and Excel or even another Word form. So I want to create a "save" and "get" buttons in Word so that when clicked, VBA code in that Word form will save those fields or retrieve the info an put it into those Word fields. What is the best and fastest way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: When I create a New document from the Word Template, I need a means of storing and retrieving information so I don't have to keep filling out those fields with the same information when I create another New document. It does not matter where I store the information, Word, Excel, etc. I'm just looking for a quick and reliable means to doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pick a "file format" for your form fields, "serialize" the form state into that format, save it on disk, then read that file back from another process, "deserialize" the file contents back into form state.

The *fastest way* to do this is to use a *user-defined type* (UDT) structure:

```vb
Private Type FormFields
    FirstName As String
    LastName As String
    Email As String
    IsAdmin As Boolean
End Type
```

Now you can `Open` the file `For Binary` with `Write` access to dump a `FormFields` into the file with a `Put#` statement, and with `Read` access you can `Get#` it back into a **same-shape** `FormFields` structure. The shape is critical; if you make a new version that swaps two fields, you've just broken the binary "deserialization"! Or you could use ADODB to `Stream` it to a file. Or you could export it manually to some CSV format. Or some XML schema. Or database... `Open ... For Binary Read` is just *one* way worth exploring, that could very well be all you need.

The *best* way to do this is highly subjective and depends on a lot of factors well beyond the scope of an answer here though :)